# Cant show custom error message when form validation fails in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Not sure what i am missing, cant show custom error message when form validation fails in Codeigniter.
Here is my code from the controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('day', 'Day', 'required|is_natural_no_zero|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_message('day', 'Error in Day');
```

But it still showing the default error message "The Day field must contain a number greater than zero."
Instead of the default error message, i want to show this custom message "Error in Day" How i can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your own messages for the rules, not for the fields...
For example with your rules, you can do this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('day', 'Day', 'required|is_natural_no_zero|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'My custom message for required fields');
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_natural_no_zero', 'My custom message for is_natural_no_zero fields');
```

Reference: https://www.codeigniter.com/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors

If you want to show the errors individually for the fields, use form_error function... Like this:

```
<h5>Email Address</h5>
<?php echo form_error('email') != "" ? "My custom error" : ""; ?>
<input type="text" name="email" />
```

Reference: https://www.codeigniter.com/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#individualerrors

Comment: Thankyou now i understand. but is it possible to add a custom error message for the field?